# How to nest ETW events

Tags: etw

I'm using TraceLogging on Windows 10, recording the events and viewing them with WPA. It works fine but I'd like to nest certain events similar to how stack traces nest.

Basically I am defining custom profiling scopes in my code and I'd like to nest them to make exploration of the data easier.
e.g.:

- Depth 0 | Scope 1

  - Depth 1 | Scope 2
  - Depth 1 | Some event
  - Depth 1 | Scope 2 ends | (0.2 ms)
- Depth 0 | Scope 1 ends | (0.3 ms)

Right now everything is flat when I drill down by Thread ID.
e.g.:

- Depth 0 | Scope 1
- Depth 1 | Scope 2
- Depth 1 | Some event
- Depth 1 | Scope 2 ends | (0.2 ms)
- Depth 0 | Scope 1 ends | (0.3 ms)

The obvious benefit of nesting like stacks is that I can expand and collapse on demand to show/hide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use ETW ActivityID to [group Events](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392926/Grouping-application-traces-using-ActivityId). Now move the ActivityID to the first or second position after time in WPA to group the Events for each ActivityID.

[image]

This should give you the grouping you want. Play a bit with it.